# How to replace pd.NamedAgg to a code compliant with pandas 0.24.2?

Tags: pandas, numpy, aggregate-functions

Hello I am obliged to downgrade Pandas versioon to '0.24.2'

As a result, the function pd.NamedAgg is not recognizable anymore.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

agg_cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
agg_df = df.groupby(agg_cols).agg(
    max_foo=pd.NamedAgg(column='Foo', aggfunc=np.max),
    min_foo=pd.NamedAgg(column='Foo', aggfunc=np.min)
).reset_index()
```

Can you help me please change my code to make it compliant with the version 0.24.2??

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample:

```
agg_df = df.groupby(agg_cols)['Foo'].agg(
    [('max_foo', np.max),('min_foo', np.min)]
).reset_index()



df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('a')*6,
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7]*6,
         'Foo':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

agg_cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
agg_df = df.groupby(agg_cols).agg(
    max_foo=pd.NamedAgg(column='Foo', aggfunc=np.max),
    min_foo=pd.NamedAgg(column='Foo', aggfunc=np.min)
).reset_index()
print (agg_df)
   A  B  C  max_foo  min_foo
0  a  4  7        5        0
1  a  5  7        7        1
```

Because there is only one column `Foo` for processing add column `Foo` after `groupby` and pass tuples with new columns names with aggregate functions:

```
agg_df = df.groupby(agg_cols)['Foo'].agg(
    [('max_foo', np.max),('min_foo', np.min)]
).reset_index()
print (agg_df)
   A  B  C  max_foo  min_foo
0  a  4  7        5        0
1  a  5  7        7        1
```

Another idea is pass dictionary of lists of aggregate functions:

```
agg_df = df.groupby(agg_cols).agg({'Foo':['max', 'min']})
agg_df.columns = [f'{b}_{a}' for a, b in agg_df.columns]
agg_df = agg_df.reset_index()
print (agg_df)
   A  B  C  max_foo  min_foo
0  a  4  7        5        0
1  a  5  7        7        1
```